# Bash can't write file from sh script

Tags: bash, awk, sh

I have a bash script that basically does some math with awk and then exports the results to a file on the machine, but it doesn't create the file or even modify the file if I create it for it. It works fine on my Mac, but can't seem to get it working on Ubuntu. Below is my code.

```
awk -v a="$topnum" -v b="${allArray[2]}" 'BEGIN { if (a==b) print 2 >"/home/skyler/Documents/SkyMine/arp_nr.var" }'
```

Comment: What are the values of `topnum` and `${allArray[2]}` and what result are you seeing in the not working case?

Comment: topnum and ${allArray[2]} both have values of 0.00064774. But when i go to look for the file that my program needs to run, its just not there.

Comment: If you add  `print a; print b;` before the `if`, what do you see?  (For me your code works equally well on mac and ubuntu.)

Comment: Try printing out something if values are not equal: awk -v a="$topnum" -v b="${allArray[2]}" 'BEGIN { if (a==b) print 2 >"./out.txt"; else print a " " b > "./out.txt" }', maybe your data source is giving different decimal places or formatting on your linux (on my linux system your example works just fine replacing topnum and allArray[2] with fixed equal values.

Comment: @jas 0.00064726
0.00064726

Comment: Still works for me with those decimal values. Let's see if we learn anything from @FBergo's suggestion.

Comment: @FBergo So I did what you said and you're right its defaulting to that else statement. Im not too sure why though the numbers are exactly the same...Any ideas?

Comment: @SkylerMartin, could you please make sure you are not having control M characters in your Input_file? Please do a `cat -v Input_file` in your Input_file and let us know if you see them.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 So there is no input file, it gathers numbers from the internet pulls them down and stores them as vars. But I did do that on the file that it's getting outputted to and there are none of those characters

Comment: @SkylerMartin, ok 1 more try, try doing `if ((a+0)==(b+0))` once in condition and let me know if that helps you?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Just ended up getting it by ditching awk and going with bl for the calculation. Thanks so much for your help, i really appreciate it!

Comment: @SkylerMartin, don't loose hope. If you could add samples of input and expected output we could definitely fix it, let me know on same?

Comment: Your username is "skyler" on that Ubuntu instance and the full path "/home/skyler/Documents/SkyMine/" exists?

Comment: I suspect him being on `zsh` which indexes arrays starting with `1` instead of `0` by default

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate `awk` and get the result into a new file using `tee` command.

**Option 1**. Using `tee` command.

```sh
awk -v a="$topnum" -v b="${allArray[2]}" 'BEGIN { if (a==b) print 2 }' | tee "/home/skyler/Documents/SkyMine/arp_nr.var"
```

**Option 2**. Using the output (STDOUT) redirection

```sh
awk -v a="$topnum" -v b="${allArray[2]}" 'BEGIN { if (a==b) print 2 }' > "/home/skyler/Documents/SkyMine/arp_nr.var"

PS. You should post your data file example, it would be easier to understand and help you.
```